# Selemium tests with PhantomJS fail on native promises

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, promise

We have an automation tests run with selenium using phantomjs.
Recently we started to use native promises in our front-end code and they are failing with following error:

> Error: Can't find variable: Promise

Is there a solution for this problem? Do we need to set some capabilities to support native promises in phantomjs?